# How could a thief buying plane tickets with stolen credit card details benefit personally?

Tags: credit-card, scams

An acquaintance had over £2,000 taken from her credit card account to pay for two flight tickets. Here's the part that I don't understand:

1. If I buy flight tickets with someone else's credit card, is there any way to return them for cash or for money in my account? I would have thought money for a refund would only be put back on the original credit card that paid for it?
2. If I buy flight tickets with someone else's credit card, intending to use them, wouldn't my name have to be on these flight tickets and wouldn't the credit card company be able to find my name?

It's of course possible that someone is a criminal and outright stupid, or am I missing something?

Comment: Tickets need not be in the name of the cardholder.  Card does not need to be present when boarding or when getting the boarding pass.  While somewhat risky, it is by no means impossible to use a stolen credit card to purchase a ticket for oneself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on how the ticket was purchased. If it is via a travel agent, the refund can be cash. Although most large travel agents reverse the original transaction to avoid fraud and save in card fees

Domestic travel the scrutiny is not great and possibly get away...

However it is not the scammer who is traveling. The scammer advertises a low fare ticket, an honest buyer buys the ticket and pays the scammer. The scammer books the tickets on stolen credit card with airlines and sends the ticket details. The buyer doesn't realize the fraud as he has genuine tickets... It may take some time for card holder to realize the fraud. Enough time for scammer to get away.